# Python Requests - ChunkedEncodingError(e) - requests.iter_lines

Tags: python, python-requests, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I'm getting a `ChunkedEncodingError(e)` using Python requests. I'm using the following to rip down JSON:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=auth, stream=True)
```

And the iterating over each line, using the carriage return as a delimiter, which is how this API distinguishes between distinct JSON events.

```
for d in r.iter_lines(delimiter="\n"):
    d += "\n"
    sock.send(d)
```

I'm delimiting on the carriage return and then adding it back in as the endpoint I'm pushing the logs to actually expects a carriage return at the end of each event also. This seems to work for roughly 100k log files. When I try to make a larger call I'll get this following thrown:

```
for d in r.iter_lines(delimiter="\n"):
logs_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 783, in iter_lines
logs_1           |     for chunk in self.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size, decode_unicode=decode_unicode):
logs_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 742, in generate
logs_1           |     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
logs_1           | requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

UPDATE: I've discovered the API is sending back a `NoneType` at some point as well. So how can I account for this null byte somewhere in the response without blowing everything up? Each individual event is ended with a `\n`, and I need to be able to inspect each even individually. Should I chunk the content instead of `iter_lines`? Then ensure there is no `NoneType` in the chunk? That way I don't try to `iter_lines` over a `NoneType` and it blows up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ChunkedEncodingError` is caused by: `httplib.IncompletedRead`

[image]

```
import httplib

def patch_http_response_read(func):
    def inner(*args):
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
            return e.partial
    return inner

httplib.HTTPResponse.read = patch_http_response_read(httplib.HTTPResponse.read)
```

I think this could be a patch. It allows you to deal with defective http servers.

Most servers transmit all data, but due implementation errors they wrongly close session and httplib raise error and bury your precious bytes.

Comment: Thank you for this. In my example the exception is actually thrown on `r.iter_lines()` so where would the above fit in there? I'm using `requests` with `stream=True` so I don't have to read the whole response into memory first.

Comment: As a clarification, this is indeed a valid approach. It won't work in python3, but there you can use `requests.get(..., stream=True)` + `for line in response.iter_lines()` inside a try-except.

Comment: For Python3 you need `import http` and replace `httplib` with `http.client` as well as `except httplib.IncompleteRead as e`

Answer (score 2):

As I posted here mentioned by another guy [IncompleteRead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55921175/3773426), you can use the "With" clause to make sure that your previous request has closed.

```
 with requests.request("POST", url_base, json=task, headers=headers) as report:
    print('report: ', report)
```

Comment: My implementation was already using a `with` clause, but I still get chunked encoding errors, so I don't think this is the root of the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing a requests.Session object across multiple processes (multiprocessing), it may lead to this error. You can create a seperate Session per process (os.getpid()).